# Error: Computation timed out. (Error code: 3)

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, land-classification, image-classification, image-segmentation

I am trying to perform Object base Image Classification, but it giving me this error, "Error: Computation timed out. (Error code: 3)". I tried to change the scale but this also not worked.

How can I do this?

Code Link:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/0998c3ccd9e1a9a85ff8cbcb1f1ec929

```
// Prepare data ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

var train_points = roads.merge(urban).merge(vegetation).merge(bareland);

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED')
                  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2020-01-01', '2020-12-31'))
                  .filterBounds(AOI)
                  .select('B.*');
                  
                  
                  
var img = dataset.mean().clip(AOI);
var trueColorVis = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 255.0, 
  bands:"B4,B3,B2"
};
Map.centerObject(AOI);
//Map.addLayer(img, trueColorVis, 'True Color');

var ndvi = img.normalizedDifference(["B8", "B4"]).rename('NDVI');

//Map.addLayer(ndvi, {min:-1, max:0.8, palette: ["red", "orange", "yellow", "green"]}, "NDVI");
//Map.addLayer(ndvi.gt([0, 0.2, 0.40, 0.60, 0.80]).reduce('sum'), {min:0, max: 4, palette: ["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "darkgreen"]}, "NDVI steps");

var ndviGradient = ndvi.gradient().pow(2).reduce('sum').sqrt().rename('NDVI_GRAD');
//Map.addLayer(ndviGradient, {min:0, max:0.01}, "NDVI gradient");

// Compute entropy and display.
var square = ee.Kernel.square({radius: 4});

var entropy = img.select('B8').toByte().entropy(square);
//Map.addLayer(entropy,
//             {min: 1, max: 5, palette: ['0000CC', 'CC0000']},
//             'entropy');

// ...

var bands = ['B4', 'B3', 'B2', 'B8'];
var FullImage = img.select(bands).float().divide(255);

// Segmentation code...

var glcm = img.select(['B8']).toByte().glcmTexture({size: 4});
//print(glcm);

// ...
var contrast = glcm.select('B8_contrast');
//Map.addLayer(contrast, {min: 0, max: 1500, palette: ['0000CC', 'CC0000']}, 'contrast');
var asm = glcm.select('B8_asm');
//Map.addLayer(asm, {}, 'asm');


var bands = ['B4', 'B3', 'B2', 'B8'];
var FullImage = img.select(bands).float().divide(255);


// Segmentation -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

var seeds = ee.Algorithms.Image.Segmentation.seedGrid(35);

var snic = ee.Algorithms.Image.Segmentation.SNIC({
  image: FullImage, 
  compactness: 0,
  connectivity: 4,
  neighborhoodSize: 128,
  size: 2,
  seeds: seeds
});

var clusters_snic = snic.select("clusters");

var vectors = clusters_snic.reduceToVectors({
  geometryType: 'polygon',
  reducer: ee.Reducer.countEvery(),
  scale: 100, // Adjust the scale value as per your requirement
  maxPixels: 1e13,
  geometry: AOI,
});


var empty = ee.Image().byte();


var outline = empty.paint({
  featureCollection: vectors,
  color: 1,
  width: 1
});
//Map.addLayer(outline, {palette: 'FF0000'}, 'segments');

// Select train polygons from points -------------------------------------------------------

var FullImage = FullImage.addBands(ndvi).addBands(ndviGradient)
.addBands(glcm.select(['B8_contrast','B8_asm',"B8_corr"]).float())
.addBands(entropy);

//print(FullImage);

var train_polys = vectors.map(function(feat){
feat = ee.Feature(feat);
var point = feat.geometry();

var mappedPolys = train_points.map(function(poly){
var cls = poly.get("Class");
var intersects = poly.intersects(point, ee.ErrorMargin(1));
var property = ee.String(ee.Algorithms.If(intersects, 'TRUE', 'FALSE'));
return feat.set('belongsTo', property).set('Class', cls);
});
return mappedPolys;
}).flatten().filter(ee.Filter.neq('belongsTo', 'FALSE'));

// Extract features from train polygons ---------------------------------------------

var train_areas = train_polys
.reduceToImage({
properties: ['LC'],
reducer: ee.Reducer.first()
}).rename('LC').toInt();

// Extract features from image ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
var predict_image = vectors
.reduceToImage({
properties: ['label'],
reducer: ee.Reducer.first()
}).rename('id').toInt();

FullImage = FullImage.addBands(predict_image);

var FullImage_mean = FullImage.reduceConnectedComponents({
reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
labelBand: 'id'
});

var FullImage_std = FullImage.reduceConnectedComponents({
reducer: ee.Reducer.stdDev(),
labelBand: 'id'
});

var FullImage_median = FullImage.reduceConnectedComponents({
reducer: ee.Reducer.median(),
labelBand: 'id'
});

var FullImage_area = ee.Image.pixelArea().addBands(FullImage.select('id')).reduceConnectedComponents(ee.Reducer.sum(), 'id');
var FullImage_sizes = ee.Image.pixelLonLat().addBands(FullImage.select('id')).reduceConnectedComponents(ee.Reducer.minMax(), 'id');
var FullImage_width = FullImage_sizes.select('longitude_max').subtract(FullImage_sizes.select('longitude_min')).rename('width');
var FullImage_height = FullImage_sizes.select('latitude_max').subtract(FullImage_sizes.select('latitude_min')).rename('height');

// join features in an image

var Pred_bands = ee.Image.cat([
FullImage_mean,
FullImage_std,
FullImage_median,
FullImage_area,
FullImage_width,
FullImage_height
]).float();

var clip_Image = Pred_bands.clip(train_polys);

train_areas = train_areas.addBands(clip_Image);

var predictionBands = Pred_bands.bandNames();

// ...

var classifierTraining = train_areas.select(predictionBands).sampleRegions({collection: train_polys, properties: ['Class'], scale: 100}); // Adjust the scale value as per your requirement

var RF = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest(50).train({features:classifierTraining, classProperty:'Class', inputProperties: predictionBands});

var classified_RF = Pred_bands.select(predictionBands).classify(RF);
var vis_RF = {
min: 0,
max: 4,
palette: ['blue', 'red', 'orange', 'green', 'yellow']
};
//Map.addLayer(classified_RF, vis_RF, "OBIA_RF");
//Merge into one FeatureCollection
//var valNames = vroads.merge(vurban).merge(vvegetation).merge(vbareland);
//var validation = classified_RF.sampleRegions({
//  collection: valNames,
//  properties: ['LC'],
//  scale: 10,
//});
//print(validation);


//Compare the landcover of your validation data against the classification result
//var testAccuracy = validation.errorMatrix('LC', 'classification');
//Print the error matrix to the console
//print('Validation error matrix: ', testAccuracy);
//Print the overall accuracy to the console
//print('Validation overall accuracy: ', testAccuracy.accuracy());
//Save Image to drive
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: classified_RF,
  description: 'classified',
  region: AOI,
  fileFormat: 'GeoTIFF',
  scale: 1000,
  maxPixels: 1e13,
  formatOptions: {
    cloudOptimized: true,
  }
});
/*
//Calculate Area
var all_classes_area = ee.Image.pixelArea().addBands(classified_RF).divide(1e6)
                      .reduceRegion({
                        reducer: ee.Reducer.sum().group(1), 
                        geometry: AOI,
                        scale: 30,
                        bestEffort: true
                      });
print(all_classes_area, 'All Classes Area in Square KM');
var igbpPalette = [
  'FF0000', //urban
  '008000', //vegetation
  'FFFF00', //bare land
  '0000FF', // Roads
];
//Chart
var area_chart = ui.Chart.image.byClass({
  image: ee.Image.pixelArea().addBands(classified_RF).divide(1e6), 
  classBand: 'classification', 
  region: AOI, 
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(), 
  scale: 100, 
}).setSeriesNames(ee.List(['Builtup Area','Vegetation','Bareland','Roads']));
area_chart.setOptions({
  title: 'Area Chart',
  colors: igbpPalette
});
 
 
print(area_chart);
*/
```